# I need a Regex to match to the end of string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to remove everything after a specific pattern ("category: ") from a sting. I've tried a few things including this, but can;t get it to work:

```
text = text.replace("category:/([^/]*)$", "");
```

and this

```
text = text.replace("category: \w+", "");
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You would need to escape the `/`s, but it's not clear why you're using those at all. Please post some samples of the input and desired output.

Comment: try `category:[\s\S]*`

Comment: Can you include example string and expected result at Question?

Comment: Remove to do what with, keep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
text = text.replace(/category:.*/, "");
```

Comment: Thanks, I used your suggestion and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

A String is not a RegExp in JavaScript. Do this:

```
var text = text.replace(/(.*category\:).*$/, '$1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
text.replace(/category:.*/, 'category:')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only concerned about a fixed string **category**, you can use .indexOf and .substr.

```
var testString = 'category: stuff-to-be-removed';
var startPoint, endPoint, truncatedString;

startPoint = testString.indexOf('category:');
endPoint = 'category:'.length;
truncatedString = testString.substr(startPoint,endPoint);
console.log(truncatedString);
```